# Getting a window property in Angular 13

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Trying to do this in Angular 13:

```
private _stripe:StripeFactory = window['Stripe']
```

And it creates this error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'

Any ideas on how to fix this?

I added:

```
"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
```

To `tsconfig.json`, but the linting errors still persist.

Comment: Try declare const Stripe; outside of your component class after the import tags and use Stripe in your code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of

```
"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
```

in `tscongfig.json`, it's [recommended to use an @ts-ignore comment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments) on the preceding line in the .ts file:

```
// @ts-ignore
private _stripe:StripeFactory = window['Stripe']
```

But there is definitely a more 'Angular' way to do what you are trying to do, but I'm not quite sure what that is. Just extrapolating from the name of the type, I'd have a `StripeFactory` in the `StripeService` that calls a `getStripe()` method which has access to your Stripe configuration and key, using that to grab the global Stripe object. You'll have to load Stripe separately and inject the `StripeService` into the components that need it.

See [this dev post for this Stripe specific solution in detail](https://medium.com/wizdm-genesys/angular-one-hell-of-a-stripe-78d7a7d2d856).

Or if you want to stick with window, you can add it to your provider array in the module:

```
providers: [
  { provide: Window, useValue: window }
]
```

Then you can inject it directly into your service:

```
constructor(private window: Window) {
  // ....do whatever you're gonna do
}
```

Comment: Awesome!!  Thanks I like the `ts-ignore`.  This is the a tutorial containing a link to the NPM package that has all the code and how it's used.   https://developer.fireflysemantics.com/tasks/tasks--angular--integrating-stripe-elements-with-angular